# Why doesn't 'import *' give me all modules?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-import

I am relatively new to Python but I am a little bit confused about the `import` statement.

When I type `from tkinter import *`, I do not have `tkinter.ttk`, so I also have to type `from tkinter import ttk`.

Does the `*` not import all modules? When I type `print(dir(tkinter))` I can see `ttk` so why is it not imported?

I expected to import all modules with `*`.

Comment: It does not recursively descend the sub packages  of a package.